# Excel: Combine all instances of text in a column

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet like this:
[image]

ID Comound Name         SubstanceID Substance Name
10  YYY/ZZZ has_part       1              YYY
10  YYY/ZZZ has_part       2              ZZZ

I would like to add 2 columns to the end of the spreadsheet:

[image]

I can't use a vlookup on SubstanceID as it will stop when it finds the first value.
I've tried 
    =INDEX($A$2:$E$3,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$3=$F$1,ROW($A$1:$A$3)),ROW(1:2)),4)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

but that puts subsequent values in lower rows, what I want is them all in E.  Is there a function to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what is the logic behind values in columns F and G. Can you explain that? Or at lease provide more examples?

Comment: Sure, sorry for being unclear.  The logic is that rows 1 and 2 have the same ID, 10.  So I would like an expression which looks at the IDs in A.  If the ID in one row is the same as the row below it, group the IDs in D together and the names from E together.

Comment: That explains what you want in F2 and G2. What about the values in F3 and G3 (which would not be checking for the value in the row below, but the one above)? (And would be listing the values in reverse order - the row above's value and then it's own value).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use VBA, you can sort lines by column A, and you don't mind having some extra (hidden) columns, you could use this method:

1. Sort lines by column A (and optionally by D as second criteria). You you later change data, you'll have to sort again.
2. In column H2, enter the following formula: =IF($A2=$A3;D2&","&H3;D2)
3. Copy/paste cell H2 in all lines of column H and I
4. In column F2, enter the following formula: =VLOOKUP($A2;$A:$I;COLUMN()+2;FALSE)
5. Copy/paste cell F2 in all lines of column F and G
6. Hide columns H and I.

You will get something like this:

```
1   -   -   1   a   1,2,3   a,b,c
1   -   -   2   b   1,2,3   a,b,c
1   -   -   3   c   1,2,3   a,b,c
2   -   -   1   x   1,2     x,y
2   -   -   2   y   1,2     x,y
```